# AfterUpdate event does not get fired on form

Tags: vba, ms-access, events

I have a Microsoft Access 2007 form and the RecordSource of the form is based on a view created in SQL Server 2005. On the form I have put a combo box that lists some values (from column field1) that are also stored within the SQL view (very simple). In the AfterUpdate event of the combo-box I have something like:

```
dim str as string
str = "select field1, field2, field4, field5 "
str = str + "from payroll_view "
str = str + "where field1 = '" & combofield1 & "'"

me.recordsource = str
me.requery
```

I have put a breakpoint on the first line where it starts with `str` and the thing is that this event does not get triggered. I have no idea why the AfterUpdate event does not get executed.

Why doesn't this event get fired?

Comment: The After Update event doesn't get triggered at all?  It won't trigger unless the text box value is changed and it then losses focus.

Comment: Yes I know that, I selected another value from the combo-box and strangely enough nothing happens. BTW the application was originally developed in msaccess 2007 and is opened with msaccess 2010.

Answer (score 3):

Occasionally Access seems to *"lose track"* of an event procedure.  When that happens, you can remind it by opening the control's property sheet and clicking the ellipsis button (`...`) located next to the property dropdown.

[image: After Update event in Property Sheet]

Comment: Thanks I will check this out tomorrow morning, I don't have the application with me.